How to design a form with a list to add more users in the same form?
I'm designing a form to add users to my system, with the option to add multiple users within the same form.
Could you help me determine which decision is better for this problem?
I have considered two approaches:

The first approach involves adding a side list to the form. Initially, this list will be empty, and when the user clicks "Add User," the newly added user will appear in this list. The process can be repeated to add more users.

The second approach features a small table located below the form. Each time the user clicks "Add User," the new user will be added to this table.


Additionally, there's an idea where each time the user clicks "Add New User," a new form will open, allowing for the addition of more users.



What is the actual question? Asking for a design, a review for a design or which one is best, is out of the scope of this site. You can ask about a particular problem with a design. See the help section for info on what and how to ask on this site.

I am asking you to review my decision and let me know which approach is better.

Depending on the width of your users' most used screen size, if you have the space to play around on the side, the side-by-side layout is better – less scrolling, can keep adding people one after another, less chances of duplicate values because the list is visible all the time, more suitable for tablet and desktop.
There is no need to display the 'Add another visitor' button when the form is already being displayed. Only when the form has been submitted will the button be required.
The 'Add another visitor' button also needs more affordance. Instead of looking like a link, may be just have it look like a proper button.
There should be a 'Save' button at the end of the form.
The placeholder text in the inputs should be more contextual. For 'Full Name', it could perhaps be 'Official full name' or something.

You can add 2 buttons.
Save (if they wish to save only one data)
Save and add another (if they want to add new data)
